# PHP URL manipulation security issue

Tags: php, url

We all know that ".." can be used to access lower levels of the file structure when used in $_GET["filename"] with

```
require("/folderwithtrustedfiles/" . $_GET["filename"]);
```

My questions is: 
If all files within **folderwithtrustedfiles** are trusted and ok for require, can this be considered as secure or is there any other trick other than .. to include files from other folders?

```
if(strpos($_GET["filename"], "..") === false)
require("/folderwithtrustedfiles/" . $_GET["filename"]);
```

Comment: What is the purpose in using strtolower? Why not just do a check that $_GET['number'] does only contain a number?

Comment: you should NEVER do this without sanitizing your input.

Comment: The "number" can also be "a12". All files in the folder are trusted and I sanitize against ".." but I would love to know if there's a trick to require from outside of the folder when the beginning of the filename and path is given. Thx.

Comment: You may want to update your question to show that folderwithnumberfiles/filenumber.inc.php actually means FolderWithFilesThatAreNotJustNumbersIn/FilenameThatIsNotJustANumber.inc.php as your naming is highly misleading Is therew anything else that you have left out that would impact any solution

Answer (score 1):

You can type the following url:

```
 http://yourserver.com/index.php?file=../config/db
```

I would enforce the base path using `realpath()`. Like this:

```
 $filename = __DIR__ . '/content/' . $_GET['file'];
 if(strpos(realpath($filename), __DIR__ . '/content/') !== 0) {
     die('bad path');
 }
```